# When hover a link change other div background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two `div`s, one with a list of links (projects) and another empty. My goal is to whenever I hover a link on the first `div`, the background of the second `div` changes to the project corresponding image. Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish  https://www.humbertpoyet.com/about/press and here is my code. Thank you

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item6">
            <ul>
                <li><h3>Case Studys</h3></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="item6 thumb">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item6 {grid-column: span 6;}
.thumb {background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: might need to share the code that related to the `second div background changes to the project corresponding image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following jQuery function. Note that you have to set a `height` for `.thumb`, otherwise it will be invisble due to no content, which results in height 0.

```js
$('.item6>ul>li:nth-child(2)').hover(function() {
  $('.item6.thumb').css('background-image', 'url(https://placehold.it/600x400/fa0)');
});
$('.item6>ul>li:nth-child(3)').hover(function() {
  $('.item6.thumb').css('background-image', 'url(https://placehold.it/800x300/09b)');
});
$('.item6>ul>li:nth-child(4)').hover(function() {
  $('.item6.thumb').css('background-image', 'url(https://placehold.it/300x500/d2c)');
});
$('.item6>ul>li:nth-child(5)').hover(function() {
  $('.item6.thumb').css('background-image', 'url(https://placehold.it/100x300/aa4)');
});
```

```css
.item6 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.thumb {
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item6">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Case Studys</h3>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item6 thumb">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add data-url to your list items, you can use JQuery to capture when the user hovers above the list item, take the desired image and replace the background of the second div.

```
<li data-url='url("paper.gif")'><h3>Case Studys</h3></li>


$(".item6").on("mouseenter", "li", function(){
    let imageUrl = $(this).attr("data-url");
    $(".item6.tumb").css("background-image", imageUrl);
});
```